# How to structure an application written in a functional language?

Tags: design-patterns, functional-programming

How is code commonly organized in FP applications? Along what lines do you separate files, modules, directories, etc.?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How to structure an application written in a functional language?

No differently than in any other kind of application:

- Every module hides a secret.
- A design decision that is likely to change should be encapsulated in a module.
- A module might export a single main type, a couple of auxiliary types, and a whole bunch of related operations.
- Module cohesion and coupling are still as important as Yourdon and Constantine said they were back in the 1970s—although in a functional language you seldom have to worry about "sequential" forms of cohesion and coupling.
- Many functional languages require one module per file, but the ML dialects offer a great deal more flexibility.  However the overwhelming practice is to put a module and its interface into separate files.  Objective Caml enshrines this convention into their compiler.

In short, it's still true that **representation is the essence of programming** (Fred Brooks), and as in any other large application, your modules should be organized to avoid exposing representation gratuitously.

The one thing that's a little different in a functional language is that you might provide a module that encapsulates some *pattern of execution* as embodied in a higher-order function.  For example, I wrote a module based on [Bubble Search](http://mybiasedcoin.blogspot.com/2007/08/bubblesearch.html); my code takes *any* greedy algorithm and automatically converts it into a bubble-searchy algorithm.  But a module like this, which is entirely about code and has no real data structure, is quite rare.

Comment: The re-use in contrast to OOP does happen at the computation (function) level, not component (object) level.